# UICollectionView Cell not filling entire screen (to bottom)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

UICollectionView cell isn't filling the entire screen. When scrolling, it then messes up (leaving spacing on bottom because the image is too short.

Things I've tried:

-Collection View Inset is "None"

-Min spacing is 0 for cells, 0 for lines

-Image inside cell is constraint to 0 on all four sides

-UI collection View is constraint to 0 on all four sides to view controller

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           

            // Even you can set the cell to uicollectionview size
            let cvRect = collectionView.frame
            return CGSize(width: cvRect.width, height: cvRect.height)


        }
```

Storyboard is made with iPhone 12 Pro max. Simulator: iPhone 12 Pro. Each scroll has a bigger image from the previous.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your collectionView constraints. The code you posted looks fine. Which view has the gradient, and which view is the blue we see peeking out at the bottom?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree 0 to all sides. Added a photo of the story board in case I'm missing something... Also added photos. Photo 1 is the users second scroll, photo 2 is the users third scroll down.

Comment: What is the UIImageView .contentMode ? .scaleAspectFill ? for me it looks like image resizing issue not a UICollectionView problem

Comment: @SergeiSevriugin .contentMode: Aspect Fill

Comment: Try .scaleAspectFill just to see result

Comment: You didn't show your constraints. Click on your collectionView and then click on the size inspector. Make sure that all of your constraints are pinned to the superview, not the safe area.

Comment: @SergeiSevriugin Just attempted .aspectFill.. No luck, still having the image "bleed" through the users next scroll. Image is just smooshed a bit narrower

Comment: UIImageView .clipsToBounds = true should help